# Eclipse with Jrebel: Debugging getting Failed

Tags: eclipse, sap-commerce-cloud, jrebel

I have Jrebel Plugin installed in my Eclipse with Hybris setup. I have set tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-Xverify:none -agentpath:C://jrebel/lib/jrebel64.dll in **local.properties**, So when I am debugging my code in Eclipse, getting below error message:

Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect
Any lead ?

Answer (score 0):

Please add this property in your local.properties and do clean all and server restart.

tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xss16M -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n -agentpath:"/plugins/org.zeroturnaround.eclipse.embedder_2021.2.2.RELEASE/jrebel/lib/jrebel64.dll"

**Note** : Please correct he jrebel64.dll file path

Comment: I have added both in local.properties to make it work for eclipse: 
tomcat.javaoptions=-Xverify:none -agentpath:C://jrebel/lib/jrebel64.dll and
tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-Xverify:none -agentpath:C://jrebel/lib/jrebel64.dll -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n